# MML — Mathematics For Machine Learning — Equation 2.110

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, change-of-basis

I am currently reading the book [Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf) [PDF, 17.4 MB]. Getting back into mathematics after a long break so apologies if my questions are trivial.

I am having trouble to understand how we get from 2.109b to 2.110 on the below:

---

[image: Click here for image]

---

Is it only because the linear combination of the c basis vectors in W has to be unique? Or is it more generally the case that this transformation is valid? That would greatly help if anyone could explain this part to me.

Additionally, I understood how to get from the middle part to the right part of equation 2.108 by writing down the summation as a sum and reorganising the elements, but I was wondering if there is a generalised version of this result, a way to immediately see that this transformation is possible just using the summation notation?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me agree with José Carlos Santos from the comments that it helps if you phrase the question in your own words. Then, all necessary information is included. From the picture one has to guess what $W , V, \Phi,\ldots$ are.
Regarding your question, the authors deduce two expressions for $\Phi (\tilde{b}_j)$ and therefore have the equation $$\sum_{l=1}^m \left( \sum_{k=1}^m t_{lk} \tilde{a}_{kj} \right) c_l = \Phi (\tilde{b}_j) = \sum_{l=1}^m \left( \sum_{i=1}^n s_{ij} a_{li} \right) c_l ,$$
where the left side comes from 2.108 and the right from 2.109b. Note that both expressions are in terms of the same basis $(c_l)_l$. Therefore, the coefficients of the $c_l$ are equal in both expressions. 
(You said you are getting back into maths after some time so maybe think about the last argument; it follows from the fact that any basis is linearily independent.)